# Should this generate a gcc warning?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, compiler-warnings

K&R C (Second Edition, section 5.5) states the following (stressed by me):

```
char amessage[] = "a message"; /* an array */
char *pmessage = amessage; /* a pointer */
```

> **amessage** is an array just big enough to hold the sequence of characters and '\0' that initializes it. Individual characters within the array may be changed but **amessage** will always refer to the **same storage**. OTOH, **pmessage** is a pointer, initialized to point to a string constant; the pointer may subsequently be modified to point elsewhere; but the result is **undefined** if you try to **modify the string contents**.

Now, my question is whether should gcc 4.6.1 (or c99) on my Linux box generate a warning while compiling following program with -Wall:

```
int main(void) {
  char amessage[] = "a message";
  char *pmessage = "a message";
  pmessage[0] = 'b';
  return 0;
}
```

(I find that gcc generates no warning. My expectation is that it should, if I am interpreting the above correctly.)

Comment: The result is the same even when I do: char *pmessage = "a message";

Comment: I don't have K&R in front of me, but are you sure you quoted the code correctly? I think it's `char *pmessage = "a message";` in which case the behavior is undefined because `pmessage` is pointing to a string literal, not an array you created.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade As-is, the code is correct, and hence does not match the error you're describing. Isn't it `"char *p = "foo";` instead?

Comment: I don't see any reason for a warning, and the compiler certainly knows there is a 0th member. Try pmessage[100] = '?'; A nice compiler will warn on that since it knows how much has been allocated for pmessage. You could trick the compiler with pmessage[ strlen(pmessage) + 2 ] = '?'; But in the end, it's your responsibility to know if you're writing beyond pmessage's length.

Comment: `K&R` is incorrect (or at least misleading) on this point. `char amessage` is indeed an array of size `strlen("a message") + 1`, and it is a *mutable* array, same as if you had written `char amessage[] = {'a', ' ', 'm' ... 0};`. `pmessage` points to said mutable array, **not** a string constant. See the [c faq, 8.5](http://www.c-faq.com/charstring/strlitinit.html). It's not undefined unless you change `pmessage` to point to an actual string literal.

Answer (score 5):

Although your quote from K&R is correct, I do not expect this piece of code to generate a warning, because errors like that are very difficult to track in general case.

For example, consider a piece of code where your pointer initially points to a block of modifiable memory, then you manipulate it a little, and then assign it to point to a string literal:

```
char [] ok = "quick brown fox";
char *ptr = ok;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    *ptr++ = '-'; // OK
}
ptr = "jumps over the lazy dog";
ptr[0] = 'J'; // Bad
```

For a compiler, it would be very tricky to track these assignments and issue a warning. Covering all cases would be impossible, because a pointer to a string literal could come from an externally linked function.

Comment: Thanks! This helps. But is what hard for gcc also hard for a program like lint? I ran _splint_ on my C program and it generates the following: 

array-pointer-chars.c:5:3: Suspect modification of observer pmessage[0]:
                              pmessage[0] = 'b'
  Storage declared with observer is possibly modified. Observer storage may not be modified. (Use -modobserver to inhibit warning)

Comment: @KedarMhaswade `splint` and `lint` are good tools for static code analysis. You can also run your program in `valgrind` for dynamic analysis of memory accesses performed by your program.

Comment: Thanks, @dasblinkenlight. I should work on better understanding what to expect from compilers and what should be left to static code analyzers. BTW, valgrind reports 'Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)' on the executable for my program. I should spend more time understanding valgrind ...

Answer (score 2):

Just because code is wrong doesn't mean gcc can generate a warning for it. If all instances of undefined behavior could be detected at compile-time, there would be no reason for the behavior to be left undefined. It could just be a mandatory error, or compile to the equivalent of `abort();` or similar.

I agree it would be easy for gcc to generate a warning in this case. But what about:

```
int main(void) {
  char amessage[] = "a message";
  char *pmessage = "a message";
  if (is_prime(some_constant_with_100_million_digits))
      pmessage = amessage;
  pmessage[0] = 'b';
  return 0;
}
```

Does it invoke UB?

Answer (score 0):

It probably does not warn because it is undefined.

Similarly I can do:

```
char amessage[] = "a message";
char *pmessage = amessage;
free(pmessage);
```

And it does not warn but should segfault.

I think warnings are for defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not expected to say anything because `pmessage` is not a pointer to const, and I guess it hasn't bothered to mention it in this case either because it hasn't done enough static analysis (you might try `-O` switches to see if that brings more insight), or because nobody made it say anything in this case -- which usually means there's no opportunity to make an unintuitive optimisation out of the undefined behaviour.

GCC supports [-Wwrite-strings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wwrite_002dstrings-430) which will raise the problem at initialisation, forcing you to make `pmessage` a pointer to const, subsequently making the following line illegal.